# AngularJS UI-Bootstrap, How to set minDate to 90 days ago and maxDate to today?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an app that is Using AngularJS and UI-Bootstrap. I have a datePicker that needs restrictions on the dates. I'm very new to angular and wonder if anyone knows how I might do this. I'm looking for a way to set the minDate to 90 days ago and the maxDate to today's date.

[my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZAONsqFMZny62dLVtCW?p=preview)

```
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );

  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();



       $scope.open = function($event,opened) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope[opened] = true;
  };


  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.initDate = new Date('2016-15-20');
  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost had it. Need to change your `minDate` variable:

```
var date = new Date();
$scope.minDate = date.setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 90);
```

Then change your `input`'s `min` directive to `min-date` and add a `max-date` to be set to your `dt` variable:

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" 
    ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened1" min-date="minDate" max-date="dt"
    datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
    ng-required="true"/>
```

Here's the [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YQePspCNaL9mQPVqFPcM?p=preview)

Comment: how can i set minDate to first of the month....i tried this $scope.minDate = new Date($scope.dt.getYear(),$scope.dt.getMonth(),1);
dt has current date object.

Answer (score 0):

min-date and max-date disable dates that falls out of the range in the date-picker-popup! but it does not validate if the user has access to input date directly into the input field! To validate the given date if the user types in date manually I used ui.validate as one noob to another:

include dependency => ['ui.validate']

in html add attribute "ui-validate"

```
 <input type="text" name="dob" show-button-bar="false"
                       class="tw-formControl"  uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
                       ng-model="vm.profile.attributes.dob" ui-validate="{outOfBounds : 'vm.checkDateLimits($value)' }" is-open="vm.calanderToggle" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
                       datepicker-options="dateOptions"/>
```

validations:

```
 <div class="tw-customValidation" ng-messages="profileForm.dob.$error"
               ng-if="profileForm.dob.$dirty || profileForm.$submitted">
            <div ng-message="date">Please enter a valid date</div>
            <div ng-message="outOfBounds"> Date selected is out of range. </div>
          </div>
```

In Controller:

```
  vm.checkDateLimits = function(selectedDate){
    var currentDate = new Date(selectedDate);
    var upperBounds = new Date();
    var lowerBounds = new Date('01/01/1900'); //replace lower bound with your 90 days logic

return currentDate < upperBounds && currentDate > lowerBounds;
```

}

documentation for ui.validate can be found here[here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate/master/demo/index.html)